# How to validate using Javascript an input tag of type text in an html form that the content of it will be Arabic/Englsih/Number?

Tags: javascript, numbers, validation

***How to validate using Javascript an input tag of type text in an html form that the content of it will be one of the following:-***

- Arabic or English Characters ONLY -OR-
- Arabic and English Characters ONLY -OR-
- Arabic characters only -OR-
- English Characters only -OR-
- Number only -OR-
- Arabic Characters and Number only -OR-
- English Characters and Number only -OR-
- Arabic or Number ONLY -OR-
- English Characters or Number ONLY -OR-
- Arabic or English Characters or Number ONLY -OR-
- Phone Number -OR-
- Email -OR-
- English string that starts with specific character like 'A' -OR-
- English string that ends with specific character like 'A' -OR-
- English string that contains specific character like 'A' -OR-
- English string that does not contain specific character like 'A'

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: is there any specific way to find out whether entered text is `arabic` or not??

Comment: Isn't all that "Any combination of english/arabic/numerals" ?

Comment: @diEcho, this is my question, how I find the arabic characters and validate the input text is withing the range of these characters?

Comment: @Alex K I mean that each one has a different validation rule as I do not need one validation rule that collects all these conditions. In practice, you will need some or all of these validtions so the answer of this question will be a reference for me and for all who need text input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I need a definition of "English", "Arabic" and "Numbers" characters.

1. The definition of the English character boundary should at least include a-z, A-Z. Non-word characters (comma, dot, parentheses) should also be included, but since you didn't specify the purpose of your validation, I will limit these to a-z, A-Z.
   English RegExp: `[a-zA-Z]`
2. I'm not skilled in the Arabian language, so I grab include all characters as definied at [this source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#block).
   RegExp: `/[\u0600-\u06ff\ufb50-\ufdff\ufe70-\ufeff]/`
3. The numbers are defined as `\d` (in JavaScript: `0-9`).
   RegExp: `\d` (equals `[0-9]` in JavaScript)
4. The beginning and the end of a string are matched by a `^` and `$`, using Regular expressions.

Brought together:

- Arabic and/or English Characters ONLY -OR-
  `/^[a-zA-Z\u0600-\u06ff\ufb50-\ufdff\ufe70-\ufeff]+$`
- Arabic characters only -OR-
  `/^[\u0600-\u06ff\ufb50-\ufdff\ufe70-\ufeff]+$/`
- English Characters only -OR-
  `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/`
- Number only -OR-
  `/^\d+$/`
- Arabic Characters and/or Number only -OR-
  `/^[\du0600-\u06ff\ufb50-\ufdff\ufe70-\ufeff]+$`
- English Characters and/or Number only -OR-
  `/^[\dA-Za-z]+$/`
- Arabic and/or English Characters and/or Number ONLY -OR-
  `/^[a-zA-Z\d\u0600-\u06ff\ufb50-\ufdff\ufe70-\ufeff]+$/`
- Phone Number -OR- *Phone numbers are too locale-dependent, construct your own RE*
- Email -OR-
  `^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$` <sup>[source 2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)</sup> (very basic mail RegExp)
- English string that starts with specific character like 'A' -OR-
  `/^A/`
- English string that ends with specific character like 'A' -OR-
  `/A$/`
- English string that contains specific character like 'A' -OR-
  `/A/`
- English string that does not contain specific character like 'A'
  `^[^A]+$`

Of course, the English character set should include more characters than `a-zA-Z` if you're validating sentences. I recommend to use `[\x20-\x7e]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`, so commonly used punctuation characters are also available.

---

### References / See also

- [MDN: Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) - A guide to use Regular Expressions in JavaScript
- [Regulsr Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#block) - Summary of character boundaries
- [UTF8-chartable.de](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) - Browser through all characters
- [Unicode.org/charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) - An official reference which documents all boundaries in a deeper detail

Comment: Thanks alot for your good answer for my simple question that I am sure it will useful for me and others who needs javascript validation in their web develpment.